# how do i add String array to JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

I am currently writing some code in a servlet that gets data from the database and returns it to the client. What I am having problems with is inserting the array of dates I have collected and adding them to my JSON object that I will return to the client.

Here is the code I'm trying but it keeps giving errors

```
dates = ClassdatesDAO.getdate(dates);
ArrayList<String> ClassDates = new ArrayList<String>();
ClassDates = dates.getClassdates();
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject Dates = new JSONObject();
Dates.put("dates", new JSONArray(ClassDates));
```

In my IDE I get this error over the `ClassDates` in the JSONArray

> The constructor JSONArray(ArrayList) is undefined

Comment: What library is your `JSONArray` from?

Comment: As an aside, replace the first two lines with `List<String> classDates = dates.getClassdates();`.  There's no point creating an instance, if you re-assign the reference on the next line

Comment: `new JSONArray` should work, if it's the org.json version.  It has a constructor for java.util.Collection, and an ArrayList is a Collection.

Comment: BTW, variable names in Java should begin with a lower-case letter.  Classes should start with an Upper-Case letter.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `ArrayList` instance instead of an `Array`. So, convert the list into an array and then pass it as an argument like this

```
Dates.put("dates", new JSONArray(ClassDates.toArray(new String[ClassDates.size()])));
```

Note : `json` API has a method signature accepting `java.util.Collection`. So, you are using some other library or older version

Answer (score 0):

```
      JSONObject Dates = new JSONObject();
      JSONArray datesJSONArray = new JSONArray();
      for (String date : ClassDates)
          datesJSONArray.put(date);
      try {
        Dates.put("dates", datesJSONArray);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```